# asp.net webApi and sending model with image property to to the client

Tags: json, image, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created and MVC 4 app and web api projects in one solution. from mvc 4 app I create products and upload related images, and from web api I send this product model to the client. 
somehow like this class:

```
class Product
{
GUID id;
string name;
string details;
string imageUrl;
}
```

for saving image to database in my MVC 4 app I do this way:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (image != null)
                {

                    string imageName = image.FileName;
                    string location = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/") , imageName);
                    image.SaveAs(location);
                    product.Image= location;
                }

                menuItemRepository.SaveOrUpdate(product);
                TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", product.Name);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                // there is something wrong with the data values 
                return View(product);
            }
        }
```

this is wep api controller for getting products list:

```
public List<MenuComponent> Get()
        {
             return _productRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        }
```

now web api sends all the products to the client

but image property in the json are absolute path:

```
"imageUrl":"C:\\Users\\Hashem\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\MyApp\\Content\\Images\\image01.jpg
```

I want the image link be something like that: `http://localhost:22012/Content/images/image01.jpg`

my client is an iOS app and after saving products to database I will download all the images using their image property.

so how can I get correct link?

Comment: How are you creating the JSON? Show the web api code.

Comment: I have added. but thats nothing special. web api just sends all the properties which are in the database without changing them. imagUrl in the database is what I have posted.

Comment: Ok, I think I have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an image is posted, you save it to a physical location

```
   string location = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/") , imageName);
```

and store the very same absolute location in your database. Instead, have the image saved to a physical location but store the relative location in your database.

```
   string imageName = image.FileName;

   string location = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/") , imageName);
   image.SaveAs(location);

   string rellocation = string.Format( "/Content/Images/{0}", imageName ); 
   product.Image = rellocation;
```

This way the JSON will return relative paths `/Content/Images/image01/jpg`.

If you need absolute server uris use

```
   string rellocation = Path.Combine( HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath, 
       string.Format( "/Content/Images/{0}", imageName ) );
```

This should return `http://localhost:22012/Content/images/image01.jpg`.

**Edit:** If this doesn't work for you for some reasons, try

```
   Uri uri = this.Request.Url;
   String appDomainPath = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Authority;

   string rellocation = Path.Combine ( appDomainPath, ... );
```

i.e. try to get the path from the current request path. This should work in an mvc controller.

Comment: I have a problem here: as I mentioned I have 2 projects one for editing products in mvc 4, and one for sending data to the client using web api. (why I have 2 projects is because of I can't have **one dependency resolver** for both MVC and web api) mvc uploads images in its content directory and web api needs to access mvc content directory. is this possible? because images located in mvc content directory! how can I solve this?

Comment: Does it matter? Images are posted with mvc so that the uris will correctly be saved by the mvc application.

Comment: I have two projects in one solution one is myApp.Web.UI and another one is myApp.Web.Api. both uses one database. from web.UI I create products and upload their images. so images will be save in web.UI content directory. and web.api send the products info in the database to the client. if add web.api appdomain to image location before sending products to the client link be something like:http://myappWebApi/contnet/images/image01.jpg. but there is no image in this directory as webUi has uploaded images to its projects image directory!

Comment: You won't add webapi domain to the path. The above code runs in your mvc controller just when the image is posted. It was you who wrote that this runs in your mvc application. If your mvc application writes a full path to the image, including the mvc root path, then how webapi could change this if the full path is written into the database?

Comment: I try to write image path with absolute url path to DB. it will solve issues. but **HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath** jsut only gives me "/". nothing more! why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46605/discussion-between-hashem-aboonajmi-and-wiktor-zychla)

Comment: although appDomainPath gives me the host address but path.combine doesn't combine 2 paths. see the shot: http://demo.chevereto.com/dM1

Comment: Add two strings or something. You are so very close and possibly you don't need help with something such basic. Glad to hear that this works.